# Induced charges, electric potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Consider a solid spherical conductor with charge Q on it, a charge q is placed at a distance r from the centre of sphere. Find the electric potential at the centre of sphere due to induced charges on the sphere because of charge q?

Comment: here are some hints. Field inside a conductor is 0 and the conductor surface is equipotential.

Comment: I know all the hints but please clarify my doubt that what are the induced charges q and - q or  Q+q and - q

Comment: Here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAQ21rImz88

Comment: I have already gone through it and totally understand that. My question is different in my question there is charge on the sphere

Comment: If I put two overlapping conductors in the region, one neutral and the other one charged with Q, and the neutral one gets polarised like in the video. They will satisfy all the constraints of the system, namely, electric field inside will be 0, so, they will be a valid solution. Hence, you can just find the solution by superposition of the potential due to charge q and the potential due to the charge Q at the centre, and that will be the answer. So, think like you're given the solution in neutral case, you put a positive charged sphere Q on top, it creates no field at centre.

Comment: Here are some questions to ponder about? There are many learnings from this problem. (1) Do you see why the second conductor you put behaves like a Dielectric? , (2) You learn reduction here, which means, you reduced the problem to basically a case you had solved before, this is a great problem solving strategy by solving a simpler problem, you were able to solve a more complex one. (3) Do you see that the charge on the hemisphere facing the outside charge can even be positive?

Comment: Charge on hemisphere facing the outside charge can only be negative because the charge outside it is positive, then how you say that it can be positive also, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're not taking the principle of superposition too seriously. You're only functioning according to your intuition, which can be wrong at times. Try to seperate the field contributions of parts of sphere and of the outside charge and try to see by drawing vectors at the centre if charge is more positive on the other side and less positive on same side of the outside charge, what are the configurations that can cancel the total contributions.

Comment: Please just tell me what are the induced charges q and - q or - q and Q+q

Comment: Please look up method of images. It'll help.